# Can I use multiple or nested elements in the Label of a Picker Item in React Native?

Tags: react-native, picker, native-base

I'm using React Native with NativeBase and would like to make the labels of my Picker more complicated than just one plain string of text.

But is it even possible to pass elements as the label, say multiple child elements wrapped in a single top-level element?

Or do Pickers only support plain text as labels?

---

As requested by bennygenel, here's a version of what I've tried:

```
export default class ThingPicker extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      initialThing,
      things,
      onThingChanged,
    } = this.props;

    const orderedThings = things.sort();

    return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={initialThing}
        onValueChange={onThingChanged}>
        {buildThingItems(orderedThings)}
      </Picker>
    );
  }
}

function buildThingItems(orderedThings) {
  let items = orderedThings.map(th => {
    const it = th === "BMD" ? (<Text key={th} label={"foo"} value={"bar"}}>Hello</Text>)
    : (<Picker.Item key={th} label={th} value={th} />);

    return it;
  });
}
```

Comment: You can give any component as child I think. Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @bennygenel: I wasn't sure what the syntax would be. Just start with the open tag? Inside quote marks? Inside parentheses, curly braces, double curly braces? (-: I guess I will go try a bunch of combinations ...

Comment: If you check the [docs for Picker](http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-def-headref) you can see that it has multiple child components. you can create your own Item component and add that instead of the default one comes with Nativebase

Comment: @bennygenel: Oh I'm too much of a newbie to React and co to spot that as a possibility - thanks!

Comment: So I tried ouputting one Text component instead of an Item and it came up blank until I gave it a label property, which was again just plain text )-:

Comment: Can you add the code you tried please so maybe I or someone might be able to help better.

Comment: @bennygenel: Done. I added a modified version based on your previous feedback.

Comment: Try returning `Text` component as a child of `Picker.Item` this might work

Comment: @bennygenel: Making it a child of Picker.Item did not work, but assigning it to the label field did work! I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Thats Great! I was gonna create a dummy project to test it out but I guess I don't have to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! It is possible, it just might not look very "right" for React/JSX code. Just create the elements you need and assign them to the label field:

```
function buildThingItems(orderedThings) {
  let items = orderedThings.map(th => {
    const it = (<Picker.Item
      key={th}
      label={currency === "BMD" ? (<Text>Hello</Text>) : th}
      value={th} />);

    return it;
  });
}
```