# Is it possible to mark certain React Native Picker Items as not selectable?

Tags: react-native, picker, native-base

In my quest to customize React Native or NativeBase's Picker to [allow headings between sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009319/can-a-react-native-picker-have-some-kind-of-divider-or-separator-between-some-it), I have figured out [how to add arbitrary formatting/elements/components to individual Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239159/can-i-use-multiple-or-nested-elements-in-the-label-of-a-picker-item-in-react-nat).

But they are all still able to be selected or "picked".

Is there a way to mark an item to say that the user cannot select it?

Comment: RN picker does have an enable/disable prop but it's only for Android. You can check it out here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html#enabled

Comment: @Raymond: That prop seems to be for the entire Picker. I want to disable individual Items. Apologies if my question wording was unclear.

Comment: Hi @hippietrail did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @AhteshamShah: No I didn't. I decided that frameworks like RN were always going to have gaps compared to the native APIs like this. I think the usual answer would be to write a new picker or add the functionality to the existing picker's code. I haven't touched RN for a couple of years now. Good luck.